# Partial Authentication with Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

My goal is to put certain pages in my MVC application behind authentication, and certain features behind authorized roles. This is usually achieved with decorating controllers or methods with `[Authorize]` and putting parts of pages inside `if(User.InRoles(...)){ ... }`.

However the moment I add Azure Active Directory authentication to my project every URL on my site redirects to the login page, regardless of whether or not the controller is behind `[Authorize]`. How can I provide the desired functionality using AAD?

Comment: Can you expand on how you perform the task "add Azure Active Directory authentication to my project"? The sign on middleware should kick in only when something raises a 401, or when you explicitly call it via Challenge. It is possible that the process you are using for adding Azure AD auth places an [Authorize] on a wider scope than you expect (like an entire class, etc).

Comment: I have used the built in "Add Authentication" when starting the project, so there are some code snippets in my Web.config, Global.asax.cs and an IdentityConfig.cs class. I don't see anything that jumps at me as surrounding an entire scope with authentication requirements. I would add code snippets, but it's kind of a lot of code. I can try starting a clean project - I believe the entire site gets behind auth by default. Would that be helpful?

Comment: If you check your `web.config`, I think adding Azure Active Directory this way adds `<authorization>` nodes to `<system.web>`, which causes the behavior you are seeing.  Check here for some samples and documentation that may help: https://github.com/AzureADSamples?page=1

Comment: OMG so simple! Can't believe I've missed that! Brendan, would you like to add this as a reply? I will mark it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brendan Green to pointing me to the answer. The main change that is needed is changing the system.web to allow users.

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Please view my blog post for the full description of code changes.

[Partial Authentication in AAD using WS Federation](http://do4urka-blog.azurewebsites.net/partial-authentication-with-azure-active-directory-with-ws-federation-in-an-mvp-application/)